# How do I save an address in Google Navigate?

Tags: google-maps-navigation

I see that there is a Star system but I really can't seem to figure out how to star a map in the application, or outside of it for that matter, it's driving me insane.

How to I save an address in Google Navigate, from my Android device?

---

Finally figured out how to do it in Chrome but I keep forgetting how. Not intuitive at all.

In Google Chrome type in an address. Once the search results pop up click the blue link on the side bar. The little popup box will show up in the map blocking the view of the map. There is a star in there. Click it. (Red Circle in picture will help.)

[image: screenshot]

But still don't know how to do the same thing on the Android app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are referring to the [Google Maps Android application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.maps) (aka maps), the star option is available from within the location details:

1. Open the "maps" app;
2. Search or navigate to the desired location;
3. Tap over the balloon with the location name;
4. After the location options page opens, you'll find on the top/right corner a star;
5. Tap the star and that location is now starred by you.

[image: screenshot composition]

## Access The Starred locations

- Navigation app

  In the Navigation app, swipe left to see your "Starred" locations. Tap the one you want to get your Navigation directions.
- Maps app

  Tap the top/left app icon, just before the search box and select "My Places".

Comment: On my Nexus 7 tablet, the star isn't always visible; sometimes I have to tap the stack-of-three-squares button in the upper right, which reveals a "star this" option.

Comment: Is it just me, or this doesn't seem like 'intuitive' design. Once you know it's great but man was I hitting brick walls with my head.

Answer (score 0):

You need to search for the address in maps first then star it, then it will show up in navigation. They are two different apps