# Can I have a list of recent destinations in Navigation?

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, google-maps-navigation

I have a Galaxy Nexus, and I use Navigation app a lot.

**Why does Navigation not have a list of recently-navigated destinations?**

Why does it show a random list of select few previously navigated locations, and why does such list nearly always missing the actual previous location that you're looking for, instead presenting useless locations where you've navigated months or weeks ago, instead of any of those you've navigated to today or this week?

**Is there any way to add a location being currently navigated into something alongside a favourite?**

Comment: Is this actually a question, or just a rant?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I save an address in Google Navigate?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/29280/how-do-i-save-an-address-in-google-navigate)

Comment: This is not a duplicate.  I don't know what "Google Navigate" is, I don't use that, the other question is actually about Google Maps, which I also don't use.  I use Google Navigation, and I cannot find an option to add to favourites a location found through "Speak destination" or "Type destination" options.

Comment: Hint: "Google Navigate" means the same like "Google Navigation", and both are part of the "Google Maps" app. See also [this thread](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/maps/nnik9tnqoFM) for the connection, and how the "stars" work. [Google's help page](http://www.google.com/help/maps/helloworld/android/share.html) OTOH simply says: *Use My Maps on your desktop to create a map of the places that matter to you most and access the map from your phone.*

Answer (score 1):

My list of recent destinations is indeed what it says.

You can "star" a location on the map, and then under Navigation there is a panel for "starred" destinations.

Comment: How often do you use Navigation?  I'm under the impression that Navigation tries to be smart enough to show those destinations that it thinks are relevant, without showing just the recent ones.  Do you have a phone from Google, with 4.2, or something else?

Comment: How do you star a destination?  I've been trying to do that forever, but haven't found any way to do so.

Comment: Described in detail at [How do I save an address in Google Navigate?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/29280)

Comment: I use Navigation fairly frequently. I have a Galaxy Nexus with Android 4.2.2.

Comment: I'm absolutely sure that I'm getting random destinations, through some kind of an algorithm that tries presenting different destinations depending on my own location.  I'm 100% positive that I don't get the most-recently-used destinations.  Is there any way to get to such a list?  My Galaxy Nexus came from the factory with 4.0, was updated to 4.1 and 4.2 and some such; never rooted or reinstalled, or whatnot.